# Not getting the output I'm expecting when using .join

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove the brackets and commas using .join. It works in other places in my program but not here. This is the code:

```
def load():
        fileName = raw_input("Please enter the name of the save file to load. Please don't enter '.txt'.")
        return open(fileName+".txt", "r")

fileToLoad = load()
fileData = fileToLoad.readlines()
code = (fileData[4])

splitcode = "".join(code)
print code
print splitcode
```

and the two outputs I'm getting are both:

```
['Y', 'G', 'R']
['Y', 'G', 'R']
```

I thought that the second output should be:

```
YGR
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you are opening a file with a line that contains a Python-formatted list (as a string) containing the elements `Y`, `G`, and `R`?  If you want to `join` the elements, you'll have to load them in to a real list first.  Do you control the formatting of the file you are reading to begin with?  My first inclination would be to try to save it out in CSV or something more easily machine readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `code` is the literal string "`['Y', 'G', 'R']`" and not a list as would be required for `join` to work as you expect.  The simplest way around this is to first convert `code` into a list by calling [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on it, or, if you can be absolutely sure the contents of the file contain nothing malicious or malformed, [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: Basically, the `['Y', 'G', 'R']` is just a code for the game mastermind. I've used eval now and it's worked great! I tried to do the ast.literal_eval but that didn't work. Not a big deal as eval is fine, but the error I got was that ast wasn't defined. Thanks!

Comment: @JaAnTr: If `ast` isn't defined, it means you're using a pre-2.6 version of Python.  Maybe it's time to upgrade.

Comment: `eval` is a Bad Idea.  It means anyone can run any arbitrary code they want in to your program just by modifying that file.

Comment: @JaAnTr - just type 'import ast' at the top. You shouldn't really use plain eval.

Comment: @jwodder I'm running Python 2.7.5. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @JaAnTr: After reading Ben's comment, I think you simply failed to `import ast`.

Comment: @jwodder Yeah, that was it! Everything is working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing something as dangerous as `eval`, you could try turning it in to valid JSON then loading that.

```
code = code.replace("'", '"')
listified = json.loads(code)
joined = ''.join(listified)
```